# pandas to_csv function changing 2d array to a single string

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I am trying to precalculate sentence embeddings and I want to store it in a csv file, so that I can reuse it later. I create a Pandas dataframe, and I have the embeddings stored correctly as a 2d array of floats (et or the ea column).

```
relevant_df.head()
```

[image]

I then run the to_csv function to store this in memory. When I load this csv file, the 2d arrays have now changed into a single string. I am not being able to use the embeddings due to this

```
relevant_df.to_csv('relevant_docs.csv', index=False)

df = pd.read_csv('relevant_docs.csv')
df.head()
```

[image]

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

CSV files are text-based and don't have native support for storing multi-dimensional arrays.

You can serialize and deserialize your array with some serializer like json when saving / reading your CSV:

```
import pandas as pd
import json


# arrays to JSON
relevant_df['embeddings'] = relevant_df['embeddings'].apply(json.dumps)

relevant_df.to_csv('relevant_docs.csv', index=False)

def parse_array(arr_str):
    return json.loads(arr_str)

df = pd.read_csv('relevant_docs.csv', converters={'embeddings': parse_array})
```